# search product based on metafield shopify

Tags: search, shopify, liquid, dotliquid

I'm wondering if there's a way to search for a product based on the metafield value.
I've 3 dropdowns, i.e. Year/Make/Model.
I have 3 metafields also, i.e. inventory.year, inventory.make & inventory.model (inventory is NAMESPACE & year, make, model are KEY). I need to search for products based on these 3 metafields.
Thanks

Comment: unfortunately api doesn't support this feature